# Queries regarding print() function

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, nonetype

```
print("Line 1")
print(">>>")
type(print("Hello"))
print()

print("Line 2")
print(">>>")
print(print("Hello"))
print()

print("Line 3")
print(">>>")
a = print("Hello")
b = a
print("a:", a, "b:", b)
```

Q1) For **Line 1**, why is it that type(None) not be executed since print("Hello") returns None ?

Q2) I am sort of aware that IIFE is a term usually associated with JavaScript but I am wondering why Python's print() function seems to display certain IIFE properties like running a function the moment it is invoked (as seen in the output for **Line 3**) ?

---

Below is the output for the code above (for *Python 3.9*):

```
Line 1
>>>
Hello

Line 2
>>>
Hello
None

Line 3
>>>
Hello
a: None b: None
```

Comment: You are not defining a function here at all, therefore you cannot have an IIFE in the first place. Writing `this(that())` will invoke `that` and then invoke `this` in basically any language. And `print` is just a function like any other function, absolutely nothing special about it. You seem to misunderstanding what an IIFE is entirely.

Comment: _"certain IIFE properties like running a function the moment it is invoked"_ - all functions "run", when they get _invoked_ - that has nothing to do with IIFE. Your confusion here rather appears to stem from the fact, that `print` does not _return_ anything, but writes to the output buffer. So `a = print("Hello")` did not do what you probably thought it would, in the first place.

Comment: And you are also confusing whatever your REPL decides to show to the user vs. what the REPL actually invokes. `type(print("Hello"))` is certainly invoked but please explain to use why you would expect anything to show up as a result of it!

Comment: @luk2302 Thank you, I think I have understood it already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An IIFE is an expression that creates an anonymous function and immediately calls it. Due to how function declarations in Python work, the concept is not really available here. You can only use this for lambda expressions which only have a very limited use case for IIFEs:

```py
>>> (lambda x: x + 2)(2)
4
```

I am not entirely sure what you think that you see in your Python example. However, `print()` is a function that, when called, will print out its argument and return `None`.

So when you do something like `print(print("Hello"))`, then the evaluation works from inside to the outside:

1. `"Hello"` is created as a string.
2. `print("Hello")` runs, prints out the string and returns the value `None`
3. `print(print("Hello"))` runs, which does `print(None)` since the inner function call resolves to `None` (after that inner call is executed)

With that same reasoning you can explain the other examples, e.g. the following:

```py
a = print("Hello")
# -> "Hello" is printed, the function returns `None`
# -> `a = None`
b = a
# -> so `b = None` since a equals `None`
print("a:", a, "b:", b)
# -> a and b are both `None` so this is equal to:
#    print("a:", None, "b:", None)
#    which explains the output
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply. As for Line 1, why is it that type(None) not be executed since print("Hello") returns None ?

Comment: @rustlecho your premise is incorrect, it is obviously executed.